# How to indicate "New" sign for fresh product on liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm using liquid on Shopify. And new to liquid.
Now, I'm trying to indicate "new" sign for products within 7 days.

```
    {% assign today_date = 'now' | date: '%s' %}
    {% assign create_date = product.created_at | date: '%s' %}
    {% assign dif = today_date - create_date %}
        <div>Time diff is {{ dif }}</div>
    {% if dif < 30000 %}
        <div>New</div>
    {% endif %}
```

It shows errors like this.
Time diff is 1607714358
Liquid error: comparison of String with 30000 failed

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All liquid operations (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`/`%`) are done via filters.

So this one here `{% assign dif = today_date - create_date %}` is incorrect.

It should be like so `{% assign dif = today_date | minus: create_date %}`.

This is your only mistake in the code.

Final code should be:

```
{% assign today_date = 'now' | date: '%s' %}
{% assign create_date = product.created_at | date: '%s' %}
{% assign dif = today_date | minus: create_date %}
<div>Time diff is {{ dif }}</div>
{% if dif < 30000 %}
  <div>New</div>
{% endif %}
```